# Stability of upwind scheme for non-homogeneous advection equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, stability-theory

I am running a model I created that includes some sediment transport. I am using the advection equation with a source. The equation I am using is:
$$ \frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + u\frac{\partial C}{\partial x} = s $$
In this case I thought that to have stability I needed my courant number $u \Delta t/\Delta x$ to be less than 1, but this is not occurring in my case. Can the source term affect this?

I am using an upwind scheme discretization in space.

Comment: I am using an upwind scheme discretization in space.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please read [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and `edit` your post accordingly. In particular, add more details about the numerical method and the source term (time-stepping formula, expressions, parameters, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

[This paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2010.08.015) presents (Theorem 2.1) the CFL condition
$$c \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x} \leq 0.5 \tag{16}$$
**assuming that** $s = s(u) \in C^\infty$ and that there exist a (large) constant $C$ and a positive constant $c_1$ such that
$$ s(u) \leq -c_1 u^{2k - 1} \quad \text{if } u \geq C \quad \forall k \in 1, 2, \dots \tag{15}$$

Based on their given estimate
$$\sum_i \Big( u_i^{(n + 1)} \Big)^2 \leq \sum_i \Big( u_i^{(n)} + C\Big)^2 \tag{17}$$
you might have for very large $C$ indeed a "blow-up" of the solution.
**However**, they also state that for the upwind scheme you get bounded variation for $\boldsymbol{u}^{(0)} \in H^1$
$$\sum_i \Big( u_i^{(n + 1)} - u_{i-1}^{(n + 1)} \Big)^2 \leq C \sum_i \Big( u_i^{(0)} - u_{i-1}^{(0)}\Big)^2 \tag{18}$$
which implies strong convergence of the numerical solution: $\boldsymbol{u}_\Delta \rightarrow \boldsymbol{u}$.